# ruby wordmove command not found in cli (gem not installing)

Tags: php, ruby, wordpress, vagrant, command-line-interface

I'm trying to install wordmove to easily push my wordpress local site (using vagrant VVV) to my server. I followed these instructions exactly, but it does not appear to be installing properly http://discover.webpagearchitecture.com/wordmove-wordpress-workflow/

I also installed ruby 2.2.4 using the windows installer, since I'm on Windows 10.

When I provision vagrant, I don't appear to have wordmove installed. When I try to use any wordmove commands, my cli just tells me how it's not recognized.

Strangely enough, I've been seeing ruby version 22 in the cli, but when I enter vagrant ssh mode, it informs me the version is 2.3.0. I know 2.3.0 causes some issues with Windows...but have no clue why it is showing that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) When you run `apt-get`, you need to run it as root.  You can (usually) accomplish this by prefacing the entire command with `sudo`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ruby-dev
```

Personally, I prefer using `rvm` on Linux for managing Ruby.  You can install Ruby as your user, not as root, when using rvm, and rvm makes it trivially easy to have multiple versions of Ruby and JRuby and switch among them.

2) I've heard multiple reports of Ruby 2.3 not working properly on Windows 10.  Unfortunately, I don't remember what the problem was.  If you have any unexplained issues, you might need to downgrade to Ruby 2.2.

3) What do you mean by `git bash`?

Comment: 1) Yes, I ended up realizing this and ran sudo in front of each command. Unfortunately, installing the wordmove gem failed, because it needed ruby => 2, but for some odd reason it only was using 1.9, even though I installed 2.3. I uninstalled ruby and installed 2.2, so I'll let you know what happens. 3) I mean git's shell, called git bash.

Comment: Still no luck. I tried with 2.2.4. The odd thing is that which ruby informs me it's rub22, but then when I go in ssh mode it's 2.3. I'm not sure how it is upgrading to 2.3 when I uninstalled it in the control panel.

Comment: When you say *go in ssh mode* do you mean when you run a command by preceding it with `ssh`?  When you do that, you're running a command on the Linux guest, not on your Windows host.  You can verify it by doing this: `vagrant ssh uname -a`, and you will see info identifying the Linux environment.

Comment: The issue was I made a "pre-provision.sh" file when it needed to be "provision-pre.sh". Ooops.....By ssh mode, I meant I enter the command "vagrant ssh", which brings me into a whole different mode. By the way, I'm still not sure why it's identifying me as having ruby 2.3 in that mode, when I uninstalled it in the control panel.

Comment: @JordanCarter Please reread my comment after the first sentence (question).  Am I right or wrong that you're running commands on the Linux VM when you use `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: Looks like it. I get this back: Linux vvv 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: So then is the answer that you have Ruby 2.3 installed on the Linux VM?

Comment: It seems logical, although I'm unsure how to check this. The whole installation process was automated when I ran my first vagrant up.

Comment: You can check it by asking Ruby its version: `vagrant ssh ruby -v`.  Or, `vagrant ssh` to get a shell and poke around, e.g. `which ruby`.

Comment: Yes, and it shows 2.3. Actually I just found out that in my provision.sh file, it is automatically giving me the latest version of ruby every time I provision vagrant. There's the culprit! Now to figure out how to modify this mess...

Comment: I accepted your answer. Although it did not answer the question per se (the answer was I had a typo naming the .sh file), it was still very valuable information and I appreciate all of your help. Thank you.